# Accessing base class private members in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have not used C++ for a really (really) long time and this question may be stupid but I could really use some help.

If my base class has a private data member and my derived class is derived publicly,  the private members of the base class are NOT inherited. But, they can still be accessed via the inherited public functions. Eg:

```
class B{
int a,b;

public:
void SetA(int);
int GetA();
};

class D:public B{

public:
SetAAttribute(int x)
{ SetA(x); }

}
```

Now, my question is as follows:
Technically, the derived class objects do not have the 'a' attribute defined on them. In layman terms, I am basically setting an attribute on an entity when the attributes does not even exist in the first place. It seems unintuitive to imagine such a concept. Did I understand this correctly?

Any extra explanation or correction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the 'a' attribute exists, you just don't have direct access to it because it's private.

Comment: You can make your base class members `protected` to be inherited, but otherwise have private properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that the attribute doesn't exist anymore, it's just that it's hidden from you. The base class methods can still access the base class members because they're not hidden from each other.

Comment: The attributes are defined on the base class objects right? If I were to set this attribute for the derived class, they don't really exist right? It's not that they are hidden since private members are NEVER inherited. Eg: If 'color' was a private base class attribute, and my derived object sets the color attribute via a public inherited function, does it get set for the derived object?

Comment: @Bugaoo, the private members are inherited but as I said they're hidden; if you try to use them the compiler will complain as if they didn't exist. But they're still there. If you do a `sizeof` you'll see that the size includes the hidden members. If you set a color attribute and the base class is responsible for drawing the object, it will draw it in the color that was set from the derived class.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps. An additional follow-up question. When designing a solution, would it make sense to have the attributes as private and access them via public inherited functions or mark the attributes as protected in the base class and access them directly in the derived class?

Comment: @Bugaoo, it very much depends on the design of the class. If the base class deliberately leaves some implementation details to the derived class, the derived class should be able to access the information it needs without too much trouble. If the base class is fully self contained and you want to decrease the coupling between it and the derived class, make everything private.

Answer (score 2):

The private base members are inherited, the compiler will just give you an error if you try to access them, since you aren't supposed to access them directly.